How to send large data from service worker to firebase in chrome extension?
I have been trying to send 4mb mp3 audio file from service worker to firebase storage for days now, still couldn't able to work.
Here is what I tried

Tried sending small(in kb) mp3 file and it worked in firebase
Tried sending 4mb mp3 file but it throw error
Conclusion I thought firebase storage has issue but same file get upload if I tried from popup.ts. I have tried with base64, ArrayBuffer and UInt8Array. none of them work. I keep getting.

Error uploading file: FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)
(anonymous) @ message-handler.ts:223
Promise.then
then @ index.cjs.js:2645
catch @ index.cjs.js:2651
background.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)

Code snippet below works in popup.ts but not in background.ts
  const uploadTask = FirebaseStorageManager.getInstance().uploadFile(
          arrayBuffer,
          `files/${"test"}`,
          {
            contentType: file.type,
          },
        )

Here is how I am sending array buffer
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            type: "UPLOAD_MEDIA_FILE",
            payload: {
              fileName: file.name,
              arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer,
              contentType: file.type,
            },
          })

Here is how I am reading arrayBuffer in background listener
case "UPLOAD_MEDIA_FILE":

 const receivedBuffer: ArrayBuffer = message.payload.arrayBuffer;

        

I have tried this as well. Please let me know if you need additional code for reference.
Passing FormData/File Object from content script to background script in chrome extension with Manifest V3
Updated:
Used navigator.serviceWorker still getting same issue.
In popup.ts
  const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = () => {
          // Send the file data to the Service Worker
          navigator?.serviceWorker?.controller?.postMessage({
            fileName: file.name,
            type: "FILE_DATA",
            payload: {
              fileName: file.name,
              contentType: file.type,
              fileData: reader.result,
            },
          })
        }
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file)

In background.ts(service worker)
 self.addEventListener("message", async (event) => {
      if (event.data && event.data.type === "FILE_DATA") {
        const { type, payload } = event.data
        const port = event.ports[0] // Get the MessagePort for responding

        if (type === "FILE_DATA") {
          try {
            const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
            const storage = getStorage(app)
            const { fileName, contentType, fileData } = payload
            console.log("Received file data:", fileName, contentType, fileData)
            console.log(fileData.byteLength)

            // Create blob from ArrayBuffer
            const blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: contentType })

            // Create storage reference
            const storageRef = ref(storage, `files/${fileName}`)

            // Upload to Firebase
            const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, blob, {
              contentType: contentType,
            })
            uploadTask.on(
              "state_changed",
              (snapshot) => {
                // Handle progress
                const progress =
                  (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
                console.log("Upload is " + progress + "% done")

                port.postMessage({
                  progress: progress,
                })
              },
              (error) => {
                // Handle error
                console.error("Error uploading file:", error)
                port.postMessage({
                  success: false,
                  error:
                    error instanceof Error ? error.message : "Unknown error",
                })
              },
              async () => {
                // Handle successful upload
                console.log("File uploaded successfully")

                // Get download URL and send success response
                const downloadURL = getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref)
              },
            )
          } catch (error) {
            // Send error response
            port.postMessage({
              success: false,
              error: error instanceof Error ? error.message : "Unknown error",
            })
          }
        }
      }
    })


chrome API in Chromium pathetically can't handle binary types. Use navigator.serviceWorker messaging instead.

@woxxom I tried, got same issue with navigator.serviceWorker, may be I am doing something wrong. I have updated the code, please check if I am missing something

Well, debug it. Set a breakpoint inside self.addEventListener("message and see what happens, make sure the data arrives correctly. BTW you can send the file directly without readAsArrayBuffer and it'll be like 1000 times faster, because blobs/files are just tiny handles to the internal browser data. Also, to respond back to the port, you need to actually pass it in postMessage(msg, [port]), see MessageChannel.

I don't think data is the issue because uploadBytes method work just fine even in service worker, that means data are passed properly. I get the issue only with uploadBytesResumable with vague error "FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)". similar issue found here as well.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6600

My point is that you need to investigate it in devtools debugger and make sure, not just guess. There may be something wrong that you'll only see when debugging and inspecting data.

Sure, thanks for your help. I will check it out
